# Adding two UIView vertically

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, addsubview

I have two UIView and I want to add detailsView as subview with other view. I am getting following error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'MovieDetailsDisplayViewController.detailsView.Type' to expected argument type 'MovieDetailsDisplayViewController.View'

View model code ..

```
enum MoviesDetailsViewModelState {
    case loading(Movie)
    case loaded(MovieDetails)
    case pageLoaded(Page<Movie>)
    case error

    var title: String? {
        switch self {
        case .loaded(let movie):
            return movie.title
        case .loading(let movie):
            return movie.title
        case .error:
            return nil
        case .pageLoaded:
            return nil
        }
    }

    var movie: MovieDetails? {
        switch self {
        case .loaded(let movie):
            return movie
        case .loading, .error:
            return nil
        case .pageLoaded:
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    var page: Page<Movie>? {
        
        switch self {
        case .loading, .error, .loaded:
            return nil
        case .pageLoaded(let page):
          return page
        }
    }
}

final class MoviesDetailsViewModel {

    private let apiManager: APIManaging
    private let initialMovie: Movie
    var moviePage = [Movie]()

    init(movie: Movie, apiManager: APIManaging = APIManager()) {
        self.initialMovie = movie
        self.apiManager = apiManager
        self.state = .loading(movie)
    }

    var updatedState: (() -> Void)?

    var state: MoviesDetailsViewModelState {
        didSet {
            updatedState?()
        }
    }

    func fetchData() {
        apiManager.execute(MovieDetails.details(for: initialMovie)) { [weak self] result in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            switch result {
            case .success(let movieDetails):
                self.state = .loaded(movieDetails)
            case .failure:
                self.state = .error
            }
        }
    }
    
    func fetchSimilarMovie() {
        apiManager.execute(Movie.similiar(for: initialMovie.id)) { [weak self]  result in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            switch result {
            case.success(let page):
                self.state = .pageLoaded(page)
                self.moviePage = page.results
                print(moviePage)
            case .failure(let error):
                self.state = .error
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for both views:

```
    final class MovieDetailsDisplayViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let movieDetails: MovieDetails
    
    init(movieDetails: MovieDetails) {
        self.movieDetails = movieDetails
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func loadView() {
        view = ParentView()
        view = DetailsView(coder: <#NSCoder#>)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        (view as? ParentView)?.configure(movieDetails: movieDetails)
        view.addSubview(DetailsView)

    }
    
    private class ParentView: UIView {
    
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        let backdropImageView = UIImageView()
        let titleLabel = UILabel()
        let overviewLabel = UILabel()
        let similarLabel = UILabel()
        private lazy var contentStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [backdropImageView, titleLabel, overviewLabel, similarLabel])
        
        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            commonInit()
        }
        
        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
            commonInit()
        }
        
        private func commonInit() {
            backgroundColor = .white
            
            backdropImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            backdropImageView.clipsToBounds = true
            
            titleLabel.font = UIFont.Heading.medium
            titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.Text.charcoal
            titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
            titleLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
            titleLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
            
            overviewLabel.font = UIFont.Body.small
            overviewLabel.textColor = UIColor.Text.grey
            overviewLabel.numberOfLines = 0
            overviewLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
            
            similarLabel.font = UIFont.Body.smallSemiBold
            similarLabel.textColor = UIColor.Text.charcoal
            similarLabel.numberOfLines = 0
            similarLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
            
            contentStackView.axis = .vertical
            contentStackView.spacing = 24
            contentStackView.setCustomSpacing(8, after: titleLabel)
            
            setupViewsHierarchy()
            setupConstraints()
        }
        
        private func setupViewsHierarchy() {
            addSubview(scrollView)
            scrollView.addSubview(contentStackView)
        }
        
        private func setupConstraints() {
            scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            backdropImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            contentStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(
                [
                    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
                    scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
                    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
                    scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
                    
                    backdropImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backdropImageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 11 / 16, constant: 0),
                    
                    contentStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 24),
                    contentStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
                    contentStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
                    contentStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: -24)
                ]
            )
            
            scrollView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 24, left: 16, bottom: 24, right: 16)
            preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
        }
        
        func configure(movieDetails: MovieDetails) {
            backdropImageView.dm_setImage(backdropPath: movieDetails.backdropPath)
            
            titleLabel.text = movieDetails.title
            
            overviewLabel.text = movieDetails.overview
        }
        
    }
    
    private class DetailsView: UIView, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
        
        let viewModel: MoviesDetailsViewModel
        init(viewModel: MoviesDetailsViewModel) {
            self.viewModel = viewModel
            super.init()
        }
        
        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
        
        fileprivate let collectionView:UICollectionView = {
            let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
            let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
            cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            cv.register(SimilierMovieCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CompanyCell")
            cv.backgroundColor = .lightGray
            return cv
        }()
        
        
        private func setUpUI() {
            
            addSubview(collectionView)
            
            //Add constraint
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
           
        }
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
            return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width/2.5, height: collectionView.frame.width/2)
        }
        
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            let items = viewModel.moviePage.count
            return items
        }
        
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: SimilierMovieCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? SimilierMovieCell
            
            let listMovie = viewModel.moviePage[indexPath.row]
            print(listMovie)
            cell?.configure(listMovie)
            return cell ?? SimilierMovieCell()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot of the error.

[image]

Comment: ok . How I needs to create instance of the DetailsView ?

Comment: Delete your `loadView` method. In `viewDidLoad` create an instance of `ParentView` and `DetailView`. Add them as subviews of `self.view`.

Comment: Please share the code I am still having same error

Comment: var view = ParentView()
        var dview = DetailsView(viewModel: viewModel)
        self.view.addSubview(DetailsView)

Comment: `self.view.addSubview(dview)`.

Comment: do I have to call this line         (view as? ParentView)?.configure(movieDetails: movieDetails)
?

Comment: I am refer to this question . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78046612/rendering-two-view-controller-content-into-single-view/78047546?noredirect=1#comment137594107_78047546. I have trying different approach to achieve the goal

Comment: I have to post complete code as per the discussions

Comment: Ok . To be more specific .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78041136/adding-two-view-controller-content-into-single-view . what will be the best way solve this problem on this question @Rob

Comment: I am expecting to combine both view controller into single view and show the content of the both child view into main view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256971/discussion-between-rob-and-nar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You report this error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'MovieDetailsDisplayViewController.detailsView.Type' to expected argument type 'MovieDetailsDisplayViewController.View'

That is a result of the line that says:

```swift
view.addSubview(DetailsView)
```

`DetailsView` is the name of a type. But you need to set it to be an instance of the `UIView` type:

```swift
let movie = …
let viewModel = MoviesDetailsViewModel(movie: movie)
let detailsView = DetailsView(viewModel: viewModel)
view.addSubview(detailsView)
```

You have not shared where this `Movie` parameter of the `MoviesDetailsViewModel` comes from. Perhaps the `movieDetails` property?

Comment: yes . It take the parameters as well . let me add the code as well .

Comment: I am trying to help you, but there are just so many different problems here! There is too much code already, and with every problem we fix, we're going to just hit the next problem, and then next problem, etc. You really should ask a single question per Stack Overflow post. And we don't want to see the gory details, but rather just a simple [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There is just too much here and so much that needs refactoring.

Comment: can you please look at this question . I have setup the constrains  correctly but I do not know why it not showing the view content. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78066759/how-to-merge-two-view-content-using-factory-design-pattern-in-swift?noredirect=1#comment137626779_78066759

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to follow your code, but the line that is giving the error is wrong. It reads `View.addSubview(detailsView)`. The bit `View` is your `View` class, not your current view controller's content view. It should probably read `view.addSubview(detailsView)` (with `view` in lower case.)

(Swift is case-sensitive, and `View` refers to your UIView class, where `view` in a view controller is shorthand for `self.view`, or a reference to the view controller's content view.)

Comment: By the way, I would advise against having a subclass of UIView named `View`. SwiftUI uses a `View` type extensively, and many people reading your code will think that's what you are referencing.

Comment: with view.addSubview(detailsView) , it show this error ..Cannot convert value of type 'MovieDetailsDisplayViewController.detailsView.Type' to expected argument type 'UIView'

Comment: I have rename it View to parentView still same problem

Comment: Gak. It looks like `detailsView` is a class type rather than an instance of a class. That's why that is giving you an error. Swift has a strong convention of using upper-case names for class and type names, and lower case variables for variable names. You should rename your class as `DetailsView`, and then you need to create an instance of that type if you want to install it as a subview of your content view.

Comment: You have multiple typing problems with your code. You should clean up your naming to follow language conventions.

Comment: Thanks I will correct it .the second class also have to be create as view like the first one ? if yes why it asking to pass Nscoder

Comment: I have created the instance like this way view = DetailsView(coder: <#NSCoder#>) but it asking to pass NSCoder

Comment: I can't make sense of your question. You need to create instances of UIView in order to install them in your view hierarchy. It's very hard to follow over 100 lines of code It is very hard to read over 100 lines of code in a Stack Overflow browser window, so I can't really get an understanding of your code.