# How to merge two view content using factory design pattern in swift

Tags: swift, enums, state, viewcontroller, factory-pattern

I am following factory design pattern . From the view model state response I am rendering the view. For movie details view I am rendering

```
MovieDetailsDisplayViewController.
```

view content.

Here is view model code ..

```
enum MoviesDetailsViewModelState {
    case loading(Movie)
    case loaded(MovieDetails)
    case pageLoaded(Page<Movie>)
    case error

    var title: String? {
        switch self {
        case .loaded(let movie):
            return movie.title
        case .loading(let movie):
            return movie.title
        case .error:
            return nil
        case .pageLoaded:
            return nil
        }
    }

    var movie: MovieDetails? {
        switch self {
        case .loaded(let movie):
            return movie
        case .loading, .error:
            return nil
        case .pageLoaded:
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    var page: Page<Movie>? {
        
        switch self {
        case .loading, .error, .loaded:
            return nil
        case .pageLoaded(let page):
          return page
        }
    }
}

final class MoviesDetailsViewModel {

    private let apiManager: APIManaging
    private let initialMovie: Movie
    var moviePage = [Movie]()

    init(movie: Movie, apiManager: APIManaging = APIManager()) {
        self.initialMovie = movie
        self.apiManager = apiManager
        self.state = .loading(movie)
    }

    var updatedState: (() -> Void)?

    var state: MoviesDetailsViewModelState {
        didSet {
            updatedState?()
        }
    }

    func fetchData() {
        apiManager.execute(MovieDetails.details(for: initialMovie)) { [weak self] result in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            switch result {
            case .success(let movieDetails):
                self.state = .loaded(movieDetails)
            case .failure:
                self.state = .error
            }
        }
    }
    
    func fetchSimilarMovie() {
        apiManager.execute(Movie.similiar(for: initialMovie.id)) { [weak self]  result in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            switch result {
            case.success(let page):
                self.state = .pageLoaded(page)
                self.moviePage = page.results
                print(moviePage)
            case .failure(let error):
                self.state = .error
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I have

```
func fetchData()
```

function to get the movies details . This function is attached with **MovieDetailsViewController** with state case.

```
case .loaded(let details):
self.showMovieDetails(details)
```

which is calling the function  **private func showMovieDetails(_ movieDetails: MovieDetails)** to display the content view ..

Here is the code complete code for it ..

```
final class MovieDetailsViewController: UIViewController {

    private let viewModel: MoviesDetailsViewModel
    private var currentViewController: UIViewController!
    
    init(viewModel: MoviesDetailsViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.backButton(target: self, action: #selector(didTapBack(_:)))
        updateFromViewModel()
        bindViewModel()
        viewModel.fetchData()
    }

    private func bindViewModel() {
        viewModel.updatedState = { [weak self] in
            guard let self else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.updateFromViewModel()
            }
        }
    }

    private func updateFromViewModel() {
        let state = viewModel.state
        title = state.title
        switch state {
        case .loading(let movie):
            self.showLoading(movie)
        case .loaded(let details):
            self.showMovieDetails(details)
        case .error:
            self.showError()
        case .pageLoaded(let page):
            self.showSimiliarMovieDetails(page)
        }
    }

    private func showLoading(_ movie: Movie) {
        let loadingViewController = LoadingViewController()
        addChild(loadingViewController)
        loadingViewController.view.frame = view.bounds
        loadingViewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        view.addSubview(loadingViewController.view)
        loadingViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
        currentViewController = loadingViewController
    }

    private func showMovieDetails(_ movieDetails: MovieDetails) {
        let containerView = UIViewController()
        let displayViewController = MovieDetailsDisplayViewController(movieDetails: movieDetails)
        let smiliarMovieViewController = SmiliarMovieViewController(viewModel: viewModel)
        containerView.addChild(smiliarMovieViewController)
        containerView.addChild(displayViewController)
        displayViewController.view.frame = view.bounds
        displayViewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        smiliarMovieViewController.view.frame = view.bounds
        smiliarMovieViewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
      
        containerView.willMove(toParent: nil)
        transition(
            from: currentViewController,
            to: containerView,
            duration: 0.25,
            options: [.transitionCrossDissolve],
            animations: nil
        ) { (_) in
            self.currentViewController.removeFromParent()
            self.currentViewController = containerView
            self.currentViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
        }
    }
    
    private func showSimiliarMovieDetails(_ similiarMovieDetails: Page<Movie>) {
        let smiliarMovieViewController = SmiliarMovieViewController(viewModel: viewModel)
        addChild(smiliarMovieViewController)
        smiliarMovieViewController.view.frame = view.bounds
        smiliarMovieViewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        currentViewController?.willMove(toParent: nil)
        transition(
            from: currentViewController,
            to: smiliarMovieViewController,
            duration: 0.25,
            options: [.transitionCrossDissolve],
            animations: nil
        ) { (_) in
            self.currentViewController.removeFromParent()
            self.currentViewController = smiliarMovieViewController
            self.currentViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
        }
    }

    private func showError() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: LocalizedString(key: "moviedetails.load.error.body"), preferredStyle: .alert)
        let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: LocalizedString(key: "moviedetails.load.error.actionButton"), style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(alertAction)
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @objc private func didTapBack(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Now I need  another view content to be merged into MovieDetailsDisplayViewController when I select the table view cell and navigate to MovieDetailsDisplayViewController which is fired in

```
case .loaded(let details):
self.showMovieDetails(details)

case .pageLoaded(let page):
 self.showSimiliarMovieDetails(page)
```

I want to merge **private func showMovieDetails(_ movieDetails: MovieDetails)** view content and  **private func showSimiliarMovieDetails(_ similiarMovieDetails: Page)** view content into single view .. which state is mentioned.

I have tried to create single view and add the instance of both view into single view but it create lots of different issue as well . Then I tried to create just UIView into **MovieDetailsDisplayViewController** but I was suggested that was not good approach and I am also not able to display the content of the view as well. Is there any alternative to solve it . If needed I can provide the view controller as well for more clear explanation.

Here is the common view controller code ..

```
class CommonViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let viewModel: MoviesDetailsViewModel
    private var viewController : UIViewController!
    
    init(viewModel: MoviesDetailsViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         combineView()
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.backButton(target: self, action: #selector(didTapBack(_:)))
    }
    
    private func combineView() {
        
        let dvc = MovieDetailsViewController(viewModel: viewModel)
        addChild(dvc)
        view.addSubview(dvc.view)
        dvc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        dvc.didMove(toParent: self)

        let lvc = LoadingViewController()
        addChild(lvc)
        lvc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        lvc.didMove(toParent: self)
        
        let svc = SmiliarMovieViewController(viewModel: viewModel)
        addChild(svc)
        svc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(svc.view)
        svc.didMove(toParent: self)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            dvc.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            dvc.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            dvc.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),

            svc.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dvc.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 50),

            svc.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            svc.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            svc.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),

            dvc.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: svc.view.heightAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    @objc private func didTapBack(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot ..
[image]

Comment: You are not using the "Factory Pattern" for this, you should use the "Composite Pattern". You can compose views by combining sub views into a root view. You can compose ViewControllers by establishing a hierarchy with parent and child view controllers. The goal is, to give it a "look" from outside (say API)  as if there were only one view controller and only one view. Establishing the communication, is probably the more complex part, while it should be easy to create subviews and child view controllers and set it up. Please give your question a clear focus.

Comment: I have added the code for common view controller but when I select form table view cell it not rendering content of the both view instead it showing loading with spinner

Comment: When you want "dynamically" add or remove views (and its associated view controller) that show as a screen, i.e. _push_ or _present_  this is _navigation_ - not _composition_.  So, when you tap a cell, and it should show a detail view, this is likely done via pushing a view controller on a navigation stack, or showing it in a detail view in a split view controller. Still, you add too much code. SO is not suitable to show how to write the whole app. So, please focus.

Comment: I just added the require code for clear explanation..

Comment: Your `showMovieDetails(:_)` still does not properly embed views and view controllers. I already answered this in a previous answer, which was your question. Please look it up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256994/discussion-between-nar-and-couchdeveloper).

Comment: I have fixed the constrains issue but still same result .  @CouchDeveloper